# SQL between query with small range error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Table A` and `Table B`

`Table A` contains

```
+----+------+------+-------+-------+
| HW | Year |  Sec | From  |  To   |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 2012 |   40 | 15.04 | 19.07 |
|  1 | 2012 |   40 | 19.07 | 19.14 |
|  2 | 2012 |   40 | 0     | 1.81  |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+
```

`Table B` contains

```
+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Year |  Sec | From  |  To   | Rate |
+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| 2012 |   40 | 0     | 9.93  |   70 |
| 2012 |   40 | 14.4  | 14.47 |   60 |
| 2012 |   40 | 14.47 | 19.14 |   55 |
+------+------+-------+-------+------+
```

My job is to match `year` and `sec` in both tables and update `Table A` with a new column `rate` from `Table B`

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[Year]
    , A.[Sec]
    , A.[From]
    , B.[From]
    , A.[To]
    , B.[To]
    , B.[Rate]
FROM TABLE A
JOIN TABLE B ON A.Sec = B.SEC
    AND A.Year = B.YEAR
WHERE ((A.FROM >= [B.From] AND A.To <= [B.To]))
    AND A.Year = '2012'
    AND A.control_section = '40'
```

I get following result:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+
| Year |  Sec | A.From | B.From |  A.To | B.To  | Rate |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+
| 2012 |   40 | 15.04  | 0      | 19.07 | 9.93  |   70 |
| 2012 |   40 | 15.04  | 14.47  | 19.07 | 19.14 |   55 |
| 2012 |   40 | 19.07  | 0      | 19.14 | 9.93  |   70 |
| 2012 |   40 | 19.07  | 14.47  | 19.14 | 19.14 |   55 |
| 2012 |   40 | 0      | 0      | 1.81  | 9.93  |   70 |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+
```

Desired output should be as follows:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+
| Year |  Sec | A.From | B.From | A.To  | B.To  | Rate |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+
| 2012 |   40 | 15.04  | 14.47  | 19.07 | 19.14 |   55 |
| 2012 |   40 | 19.07  | 14.47  | 19.14 | 19.14 |   55 |
| 2012 |   40 | 0      | 0      | 1.81  | 9.93  |   70 |
+------+------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+
```

Why am I getting the other two additional rows?

Comment: you should better explain `in above result I should be only getting`?

Comment: Obvisously `A.To` and `B.To` comparison is not numeric.  What is the schema of the two tables?  Can you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: It looks like your overall join criteria (including WHERE conditions) is not unique. To clarify your issue, why do you think the first result (in the results you get) does not belong?

Comment: Add A.HW to the select clause and it will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Uueerdo Probably because `19.07 <= 9.93` is false...

Comment: @ForguesR yeah, good cache, the result columns were mushed together so much it made it difficult for me to spot that. Looks like the results of string comparisons.

Comment: From and To is not in range i.e. for 0 to 9.93 rate should be 70 , for 14.4 to 14.47 rate is 60 , for 14.47 to 19.14 rate is 55 but the results show different. @DanBracuk it is same even after doing it.

Comment: You mention  `update Table A ` but you are using `Select`. Do you want to display the rate or update Table A by adding rate as a new column to it?

Comment: Show the column along with the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get are wrong because you are probably not using a numeric data type for the columns `From` and `To`.  See :

```
 SELECT '19.07' <= '9.93' ## Returns 1 (true);
 SELECT 19.07 <= 9.93     ## Returns 0 (false);
```

Thus all the `From` and `To` comparisons in your query are probably wrong and that's why you are getting an unexpected result.

By using the appropriate data type, `DECIMAL(6,2)` for instance, your query will return the expected result.  See this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07906/17).

Comment: can you once check the fiddle? I am unable to see